# Why doesn't this for loop terminate when it should?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i].order = "l1l2";
}
var tempwords = list.words;
for (i = 0; i < tempwords.length; i++) {
    tempwords[i].order = "l2l1";
    words.push(tempwords[i]);
}
```

So I have an array of objects and I want this script to get every object in the array and add the order object to it with value l1l2. Then I want it to get the array again, do exactly the same but this time with value l2l1 and then merge the two arrays together but for some reason the second for loop does not seem to terminate. The length of tempwords keeps increasing for some reason. list.words.length and words.length seem to be increasing as well while only words.length should increase.

Comment: Is `words` and `list.words` the same list?

Comment: `var tempwords = list.words;` should be `var tempwords = words;`

Comment: tempwords length is always increasing as you are pushing in words....

Comment: yes they are the same

Comment: I don't see how im pushing in words in tempwords.

Comment: `words.push(tempwords[i]);`

Comment: @user3919441 - You have a wrong assumption about lists and objects in JavaScript. Try `var a=[1,2,3]; var b=a; a.push(4);`. `b` will also have `4`.

Comment: `var tempwords = list.words;` doesn't do what you think it does. Both variables are referring to the same array, hence pushing a new member to `words` will also reflect to `tempwords`.

Comment: That line is supposed to push the objects of tempwords into words.

Comment: Thank you Kobi and Teemu. I did not know that. I thought it was the same as in Java.

Comment: @user3919441 - I'm pretty sure it is the same in Java `:)`

Comment: so changing list.words to list.words.slice(0) should fix it right?

Comment: Wait, actually the loop will stop as expected, but *all* items will be set to `"l2l1"`, including items of `list.words`. This is due to the fact that objects are not copied in javascript. Thus, in `var a = [{ order: 'l1l2' }]; var b = a.slice(0); b.push(a[0]);`, `a[0] === b[0] === b[1]`. Then, `b[1].order = "l2l1";` will modify `a[0]` and `b[0]` as well :-/